# pyspark : Configparser is not reading config file from google storage

Tags: python, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, configparser

I am trying to read a config file from google storage bucket via pyspark script run by dataproc. But the file is not read.

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('gs://<<google_bucket_location>>/example.ini')
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that configparser reads only local files. The best option is to download the config file from GCS into a tmp directory and read it form there.